# Can Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatConditions contain more than 3 conditional formats?

Tags: c#, excel

The documentation in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.formatconditions says:

> The FormatConditions collection can contain up to three conditional formats.

Which is further reinforced in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.formatconditions.add?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_FormatConditions_Add_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlFormatConditionType_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_, which says:

> You cannot define more than three conditional formats for a range.

However, I **can** define more than 3 conditional formats for a range of cells.  I did so in a C# application I developed in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, using a target framework of .NET Framework 3.5, and referencing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll version 12.0.0.0.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace test
{
  class Program
  {
    static int Main( string[] args )
    {
      //------------------------------
      // Parse command line for output path.
      string path = null;
      if ( args.Length > 0 )
      {
        path = args[0];
      }
      Console.WriteLine( "Output path: '" + path + "'" );

      //------------------------------
      // The Excel application.
      Application app = new Application();

      // Disable appearance of Excel window.
      app.Visible = false;

      // Disable screen updates, so that changing cells is faster.
      app.ScreenUpdating = false;

      // Disable prompts, like whether to overwrite an existing file.
      app.DisplayAlerts = false;

      //------------------------------
      // The workbook.
      Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value );

      //------------------------------
      // The worksheet.
      Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.ActiveSheet;

      //------------------------------
      // The first row.
      int r = 1;
      int c = 1;
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "R";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "Y";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "G";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "B";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "X";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "R";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "Y";
      sheet.Cells[r, c++] = "G";

      //------------------------------
      // The cells to format.
      Range range = sheet.get_Range( sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[1, 8] );
      range.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
      range.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
      range.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;


      //------------------------------
      // *** Add more than 3 conditional format rules as a test. ***
      //------------------------------


      //------------------------------
      // Red status.
      FormatCondition cond = (FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,    // type 
        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,    // operator
        "R",                                  // formula1: The value or expression associated with the conditional format. 
        Type.Missing,                         // formula2
        Type.Missing,                         // object string
        Type.Missing,                         // textOperator
        Type.Missing,                         // dateOperator
        Type.Missing                          // scopeType
      );

      cond.Font.Bold = true;
      cond.Font.Color = XlColor.WHITE;
      cond.Interior.Color = XlColor.STATUS_RED;

      //------------------------------
      // Yellow status.
      cond = (FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
        "Y",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing );

      cond.Font.Bold = true;
      cond.Interior.Color = XlColor.STATUS_YELLOW;

      //------------------------------
      // Green status.
      cond = (FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
        "G",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing );

      cond.Font.Bold = true;
      cond.Font.Color = XlColor.WHITE;
      cond.Interior.Color = XlColor.STATUS_GREEN;

      //------------------------------
      // Blue status.
      // *** The 4th condition I supposedly should not have. ***
      cond = (FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
        "B",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing );

      cond.Font.Bold = true;
      cond.Font.Color = XlColor.WHITE;
      cond.Interior.Color = XlColor.STATUS_BLUE;

      //------------------------------
      // Another status for good measure.
      // *** The 5th condition I supposedly should not have. ***
      cond = (FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual,
        "X",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing );

      cond.Font.Bold = true;
      cond.Font.Color = XlColor.WHITE;
      cond.Interior.Color = XlColor.BLACK;


      //------------------------------
      // Save workbook to output path.
      book.SaveAs( path,                  // fileName
        XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,   // fileFormat
        Type.Missing,                     // password
        Type.Missing,                     // writeResPassword
        false,                            // readOnlyRecommended
        false,                            // createBackup
        XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,    // accessMode
        XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges,  // conflictResolution: Should not matter since the workbook I create is not shared, but probably benign to specify it.
        Type.Missing,                     // addToMru
        Type.Missing,                     // textCodepage
        Type.Missing,                     // textVisualLayout
        Type.Missing                      // local
      );

      Console.WriteLine( "Saved workbook: '" + book.FullName + "'" );

      book.Close( true,   // saveChanges: If true, save changes to the workbook.  If there is not yet a file name associated with the workbook, then given fileName is used.
        path,             // fileName:  If saveChanges is true and fileName is omitted, the user is asked to supply a file name.
        false             // routeWorkbook
      );

      return 0;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// B8G8R8 color values that can be used with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel API.
  /// </summary>
  public enum XlColor
  {
    BLACK = 0x000000,
    WHITE = 0xffffff,
    RED = 0x0000ff,
    GREEN = 0x00ff00,
    BLUE = 0xff0000,
    YELLOW = 0x00ffff,
    MAGENTA = 0xff00ff,
    CYAN = 0xffff00,

    STATUS_RED = 0x0707be,
    STATUS_YELLOW = 0x00ffff,
    STATUS_GREEN = 0x50b000,
    STATUS_BLUE = 0x784e1f,
  };
}
```

I open the resulting Excel file using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.  All 5 of the conditional formatting rules I defined work.

[image]

Am I just lucky?  Or is the documentation outdated?

Comment: I can confirm that I'm able to add more than 3 format conditions on the same range, so it seems like the documentation is wrong. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 targeting .NET 4.6.1 with version 16.0 of the Excel Object library

Comment: Thanks @MaxKlein for the confirmation.  I have since abandoned Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and now use ClosedXML.

Comment: did you try other libraries too? I've seen EPPlus recommended a few times and I'm wondering if there are any significant differences

Comment: No, in a C# environment I have only tried OpenXML and ClosedXML.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! I didn't know about OpenXML/ClosedXML before